# How to check if one column in a dataframe is exactly equal to a column in another dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes with different data but all have a date column.  I need to make sure each dataframe's date column exactly matches(data/row etc) something like:

```
if df1['Date'] == df2['Date'] == df3['Date']:
```

I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

I was thinking just comparing them and producing a true/false and checking that

```
(np.where(df1['Date'] == df2['Date'], 'True', 'False')
```

but this seems inefficient.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Shubham pointed out to use

```
df1['Date'] == df2['Date']
```

however this produces an error

```
if df1['Date'] == df2['Date']:

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I looked into it and when using and/or you can just change to &/| to avoid error but I do not know how to make this if statement work.

Thanks

Comment: What about `(df.IDOne == dg.IDOne) & (dg.IDOne == dh.IDOne)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the error you are getting use .all()

```
if (df1['Date'] == df2['Date']).all():
```

Using np.where is fine, you can also use isin: `df1['Date'].isin(df2['Date'])`
and with value_counts check if there was any date that did not match

```
False not in df1['Date'].isin(df2['Date']).value_counts()
```